# REST Webservice - Sample Code - Gives HTTP 302 response

Tags: java, web-services, http-status-code-302, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am just trying REST webservice; Standard Sample; 
While I am able to create the war and load it into WSO2 AS, when I try to connect it with client I get a response of HTTP 302; I was wondering where the mistake could be; 
Following are my file listings.

```
package com.indu.rs.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// POJO, no interface no extends

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</h1></body>" + "</html> ";
    }

} // class
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>com.indu.rs.test</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.indu.rs.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**client**

```
package com.indu.rs.test.client;

import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class RsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

        // Fluent interfaces
        System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(ClientResponse.class).toString());

        // Get plain text
        System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));

        // Get XML
        System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(
                MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class));

        // The HTML
        System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(
                MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class));


    }

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(
                "http://localhost:9100/com.indu.rs.test").build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `getBaseURI` with `http://localhost:9100/`

Answer (score 1):

302 means you are being redirected. Connect to the endpoint using curl --verbose, and take a look at the Location: header. It should give you a clue about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the solution I finally got from a friend of mine;

in web.xml 
change  /rest  -->  /rest/*

Create the war file and upload into the server (in my case WSO2);
When the server uploads the war file, it creates it with a context (in my case RSTest)

Finally go to a browser type:

```
http://localhost:9100/RSTest/rest/hello
```

and you will see a successful result  (in this case Hello Jersey )

-Indu